# Elasticsearch Histogram of visits

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I'm quite new to Elasticsearch and I fail to build a histogram based on ranges of visits. I am not even sure that it's possible to create this kind of chart by using a single query in Elasticsearch, but I'm the feeling that could be possible with pipeline aggregation or may be scripted aggregation.

Here is a test dataset with which I'm working:

```
PUT /test_histo
{ "settings": { "number_of_shards": 1 }}

PUT /test_histo/_mapping/visit
{
   "properties": {
      "user": {"type": "string" },
      "datevisit": {"type": "date"},
      "page": {"type": "string"}
   }
}

POST test_histo/visit/_bulk
{"index":{"_index":"test_histo","_type":"visit"}}
{"user":"John","page":"home.html","datevisit":"2015-11-25"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_histo","_type":"visit"}}
{"user":"Jean","page":"productXX.hmtl","datevisit":"2015-11-25"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_histo","_type":"visit"}}
{"user":"Robert","page":"home.html","datevisit":"2015-11-25"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_histo","_type":"visit"}}
{"user":"Mary","page":"home.html","datevisit":"2015-11-25"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_histo","_type":"visit"}}
{"user":"Mary","page":"media_center.html","datevisit":"2015-11-25"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_histo","_type":"visit"}}
{"user":"John","page":"home.html","datevisit":"2015-11-25"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_histo","_type":"visit"}}
{"user":"John","page":"media_center.html","datevisit":"2015-11-26"}
```

If we consider the ranges [1,2[, [2,3[, [3, inf.[

The expected result should be :

- [1,2[ = 2
- [2,3[ = 1
- [3, inf.[ = 1

All my efforts to find the histogram showing a **customer visit frequency** remained to date unsuccessful. I would be pleased to have a few tips, tricks or ideas to get a response to my problem.

Comment: could you be more specific about what kind of output you are expecting? what does _If we consider the ranges [1,2[, [2,3[, [3, inf.[_ mean?

Comment: I would like the know the customer visit frequency, i.e.How often do they visit? In this example **[1,2[** means once a period time, **[2,3[** means twice a period time, ....the period time is not determined here but it could be the week or the month, etc.

Comment: Should I conclude that is not possible to get a customer visit frequency from a log as described ?

Comment: can you explain how **[1,2[ = 2** and **[2,3[ = 1** in the above example?

Comment: [1,2[ = 2 because 2 users have visited the website once on the period (Jean and Robert in my dataset), [2,3[=1 because 1 user has visited twice (Mary), etc...[a,b[ = x means that <x> visitors have at least <a> visits and less than <b> visits on the period

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways you can do it.

First is doing it in ElasticSearch which will require `Scripted Metric Aggregation`. You can read more about it [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html).

Your query would look like this

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "visitors_over_time": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "datevisit",
        "interval": "week"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "no_of_visits": {
          "scripted_metric": {
            "init_script": "_agg['values'] = new java.util.HashMap();",
            "map_script": "if (_agg.values[doc['user'].value]==null) {_agg.values[doc['user'].value]=1} else {_agg.values[doc['user'].value]+=1;}",
            "combine_script": "someHashMap = new java.util.HashMap();for(x in _agg.values.keySet()) {value=_agg.values[x];if(value<3){key='[' + value +',' + (value + 1) + '[';}else{key='[' + value +',inf[';}; if(someHashMap[key]==null){someHashMap[key] = 1}else{someHashMap[key] += 1}}; return someHashMap;"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

where you can change period of time in `date_histogram` object in the field `interval` by values like day, week, month.

Your response would look like this

```
{
  "took": 5,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 7,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "visitors_over_time": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key_as_string": "2015-11-23T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1448236800000,
          "doc_count": 7,
          "no_of_visits": {
            "value": [
              {
                "[2,3[": 1,
                "[3,inf[": 1,
                "[1,2[": 2
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Second method is to the work of `scripted_metric` in client side. You can use the result of `Terms Aggregation`. You can read more about it [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html).

Your query will look like this
GET test_histo/visit/_search

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "visitors_over_time": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "datevisit",
        "interval": "week"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "no_of_visits": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "user",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the response will be

```
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 7,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "visitors_over_time": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key_as_string": "2015-11-23T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1448236800000,
          "doc_count": 7,
          "no_of_visits": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "john",
                "doc_count": 3
              },
              {
                "key": "mary",
                "doc_count": 2
              },
              {
                "key": "jean",
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "key": "robert",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

where on the response you can do count for each `doc_count` for each period.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html

If you whant to show it in fancy already fixed UI use Kibana.

A query like this:

```
GET _search
{
   "query": {
      "match_all": {}
   }, 
   {
    "aggs" : {
        "visits" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "datevisit",
                "interval" : "month"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Should give you a histogram, I don't have elastic here at the moment so I might have some fat finggered typos.

Then you could ad query terms to only show histogram for specific page our you could have an aouter aggregation bucket wich aggregates / page or user.

Something like this:

```
GET _search
{
   "query": {
      "match_all": {}
   }, 
   {
       {
    "aggs" : {
        "users" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "user",
            },
        "aggs" : {
            "visits" : {
                "date_histogram" : {
                    "field" : "datevisit",
                    "interval" : "month"
                }
            }
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Richard L but that is not my concern.Your query gives the number of visits per user and per unit of time (month in this case). The x-Axis shoud be based on ranges (as given for example) and Y-axis counts the numbers of visitors on the period of time per range of visit frequency.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to this solution:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "aggs": {
        "periods": {
            "filters": {
                "filters": {
                    "1-2": {
                        "range": {
                            "datevisit": {
                                "gte": "2015-11-25", 
                                "lt": "2015-11-26"
                            }
                        }
                    }, 
                    "2-3": {
                        "range": {
                            "datevisit": {
                                "gte": "2015-11-26", 
                                "lt": "2015-11-27"
                            }
                        }
                    }, 
                    "3-": {
                        "range": {
                            "datevisit": {
                                "gte": "2015-11-27", 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "users": {
                    "terms": {"field": "user"}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Step by step: 
Filter aggregation: You can define ranged values for the next aggregation, in this case we define 3 periods based on date range filter
Nested Users aggregation: This aggregation returns as many results as filters you'd defined. So, in this case, you'll get 3 values using range date filtering

You'll get a result like this:

```
{   
    ...
    "aggregations" : {
        "periods" : {
            "buckets" : {
                "1-2" : {
                    "users" : {
                        "buckets" : [
                            {"key" : XXX,"doc_count" : NNN},
                            {"key" : YYY,"doc_count" : NNN},
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "2-3" : {
                    "users" : {
                        "buckets" : [
                            {"key" : XXX1,"doc_count" : NNN1},
                            {"key" : YYY1,"doc_count" : NNN1},
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "3-" : {
                    "users" : {
                        "buckets" : [
                            {"key" : XXX2,"doc_count" : NNN2},
                            {"key" : YYY2,"doc_count" : NNN2},
                        ]
                    }
                },
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Try it, and tell if it works